# Android resize TextView text-size so that it is singleline

Tags: android, textview

HY

I want a TextView to have a maximum textSize of 30dip, but if the screen is to small to display everything, the size should be adjusted. Is there a way to do so?

```
<style name="cimbaliHeadline" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large">
    <item name="android:textSize">30dip</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

First things first:  ALWAYS define text size with sp, this way you shouldn't even have this issue.

If you have a string that is simply too long to display on a screen, you could either use android:ellipsize="true" or use something along the lines of this:

```
if(myTextView.height > defaultTextView.height)
    myTextView.setTextSize(smallerTextUnit, smallerTextSize);
```

where defaultTextView is a dummy view that you can set to invisible somewhere in your layout.

Hope this helps.